# Mute single speaker?

Tags: audio, speakers

The left internal speaker on my 2018 MBP fried ([sounds annoying common](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-15-2017-left-speaker-blown-out.2085264/)). I don't really want to take it in to get it fixed, and I'm hoping I can just disable the left one and use the right one.

In Audio Devices, there is a checkbox to mute channel 1 (left), but I can't actually click it.

Is there another way to turn off a single internal speaker on a MBP?

Comment: Can you use the Balance slider under System Preferences > Sound > Output ?

Comment: Thanks Fyrefly! That did it. If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The speakers are [pretty cheap](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13%22-Touch-Bar-Mid-2018/Speakers), and from a quick view of the photographs, they look really easy to access and replace. Have you considered repairing this yourself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple method, as already stated, System Prefs > Sound > Output. Set balance slider to the right.

More comprehensive method, in case you are listening to stereo & need the information otherwise missing from the other speaker - you also need…

System Prefs > Accessibility > Audio

check 'Play stereo audio as mono'

This will sum the left & right channels so you will hear both from the one speaker after you balance across to it.

Answer (score 7):

Open System Preferences > Sound > Output look for the balance slider and adjust as needed.